# Could not add entry to cache (/Users/android/.gradle/7.5.1/checksums/sha1-checksums.bin). > java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, runtime-error

I was getting these 2 errors while running my react native project.

- What went wrong:
  Could not add entry '/Users/saadafridi/.gradle/.tmp/gradle_download14928641310389655157bin' to cache sha1-checksums.bin (/Users/saadafridi/Desktop/mobileapp/android/.gradle/7.5.1/checksums/sha1-checksums.bin).

> java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().
> Cannot lock checksums cache (/Users/saadafridi/Desktop/mobileapp/android/.gradle/7.5.1/checksums) as it has already been locked by this process.

I ran the following 2 cmds.

1. yarn android
2. cd android --> ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 1):

For solving the above errors in react native all you need to do is to follow the steps.

1. cd android.
2. ./gradlew --stop

then re-run your app, it worked for me perfectly.